# How do I validate a name field in HTML 5 using Patterns?

Tags: javascript, validation

Im trying to validate a name field using javascript regex. The regex I have developed doesnt seem to work:

```
name.match(/^([a-zA-Z ]){2}$/)
```

What im looking to do, is have the field validated using regex that would produce the following results:

- Accept only alphabetic characters.
- containing 2 words (so 1 space)

A valid entry would be "test name".

An invalid entry would be "test name jr", or "test" or "".

Case isnt important.

Can anyone help me fix my pattern? Not sure why it doesnt work.

Comment: `/^[a-zA-Z]+(\s[a-zA-Z]+)?$/`

Comment: For future - you can use http://refiddle.com/ to see how your regex works.

Comment: @Tushar thanks, but it doesnt quite work right. Your regex returns a match for "Tom", which doesnt contain 2 words.

Comment: Remove the`?` from above regex

Comment: [`^[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/uZ0aF3/1)

Comment: Tushar that worked perfectly. Thank you.